# How to change listview's button background color when button clicked in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

In my application, I keep yes and no button in listview as an item. **setOnClickListener** is defined in **Adapter** class. I have a problem with this. After I scroll the listview, I see the changed button in another row. How can I resolve my issue ?

```
public class QuizAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final String FONTH_PATH_1 = "fonts/Brandon_reg.otf";
    private static final String FONTH_PATH_2 = "fonts/Brandon_bld.otf";

    private ArrayList<Question> questionList = new ArrayList<Question>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private Context context;

    public QuizAdapter(Context context) {
        super();
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void addListItem(final Question item) {
        questionList.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return questionList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Question getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return questionList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;


        Question currentQuestion = getItem(position);

        Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                FONTH_PATH_1);
        Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                FONTH_PATH_2);

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quiz_list, null);

            holder.questionCounterTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.questionCounterTextView);
            holder.questionCounterTextView.setTypeface(font2);

            holder.questionTextView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.questionTextView);
            holder.questionTextView.setTypeface(font1);

            holder.yesButton = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
            holder.yesButton.setTypeface(font2);

            holder.noButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.noButton);
            holder.noButton.setTypeface(font2);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        }

        holder.yesButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                holder.yesButton.setBackgroundColor(R.color.Gray);
            }
        });

        holder.questionCounterTextView.setText(Integer.toString(position + 1));

        holder.questionTextView.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestionMessage());

        return convertView;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView questionCounterTextView, questionTextView;
        public Button yesButton, noButton;
    }

}
```

xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="...." >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/flagImageView"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/flag" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/questionCounterTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/flagImageView"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/flagImageView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/flagImageView"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/flagImageView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:textColor="@color/White" 
            android:textSize="@dimen/question_counter_text_size"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/questionTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/flagImageView"
            android:text="@string/loremIpsum2"
            android:textColor="@color/Blue"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/quizLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="640" >

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="30" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yesButton"
            style="@style/button_type"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="275"
            android:background="@color/QuizGreen"
            android:text="@string/yes"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="@dimen/question_button_text_size" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="30" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/noButton"
            style="@style/button_type"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="275"
            android:background="@color/QuizOrange"
            android:text="@string/no"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="@dimen/question_button_text_size" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="30" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Definitely the ViewHolder makes the bug, did you try selector before for changing background color?

Comment: @Pedram, I don't want to use selector because I have 2 buttons and each of them can change when one of them is clicked. For example, no button may be clicked after yes button is clicked. Same issue may be occured with holder. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem with defining a new String in Question class which is kept user answer. Controlling yes or no than change the background.

```
        holder.yesButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (currentQuestion.getUserAnswer() == null) {
                questionList.get(position).setUserAnswer("TRUE");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (currentQuestion.getUserAnswer().equals("FALSE")) {
                questionList.get(position).setUserAnswer("TRUE");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

    holder.noButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (currentQuestion.getUserAnswer() == null) {
                questionList.get(position).setUserAnswer("FALSE");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (currentQuestion.getUserAnswer().equals("TRUE")) {
                questionList.get(position).setUserAnswer("FALSE");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });

    if (currentQuestion.getUserAnswer() == null) {
        holder.yesButton.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.QuizGreen));
        holder.noButton.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.QuizOrange));
    } else if (currentQuestion.getUserAnswer().equals("TRUE")) {
        holder.yesButton.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.NewsFeedDividerGray));
        holder.noButton.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.QuizOrange));
    } else {
        holder.yesButton.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.QuizGreen));
        holder.noButton.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.NewsFeedDividerGray));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not using the holder, and doing something like this?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent();
    Button bttn = (Button)rl.findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
    bttn.setBackgroundColor(R.color.Gray);  
}
```

Comment: Nope, this approach reduces the reusability of view. Using ViewHolder is better I think. Thank you.

Comment: You still use the viewholder in exactly the same way you were using it before. You just change the onClick method to get the button from the clicked parent.